# How to stop fcitx-unikey stop showing the input in a small window

Tags: fcitx

Whenever I tried to type in Vietnamese it keeps showing the input window. Is there anyways to remove the window? Please help me. Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TU3QX.png)

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *Deepin is neither Ubuntu nor flavor of Ubuntu*

Comment: @guiverc, your observation is sharp. And now I do know *this* is the look of the famous Chinese version debian...

Answer (score 0):

The small window is called 'Suggest', which predicts the word that you are going to type.

[image: Mozc]

You may find a Unikey Settings window, which likely looks like this.  Toggle off these checkboxes.